# График неправильной окружность

Tags: c#, алгоритм, математика

Имеется List структур хранящих результаты и координаты функции двух переменных (z и x,y соответственно). Нужно построить линии уровня функции f(x,y)=0.5x^2+0.5y^2-x-2y+5 т.е линии соединяющие точки с координатами(x,y) спроецированными на плоскость П1. По сути линии уровня представляют собой вытянутые окружность. В чем вопрос: в какой последовательности соединять точки представленные координатами (x,y), как их сортировать, что бы получить те самые вытянутые окружности. Сравнение точек реализую так

```
line.Sort((FResuslt one, FResuslt two) =>
         {
              return (one.x + one.y).CompareTo(two.y + two.x);
         });
```

Comment: Что такое "сравнение точек" и к чему оно тут вообще? И почему именно линии уровня представляют собой "вытянутую окружность"? Линии уровня могут иметь самые разные формы. Откуда вдруг взялась именно "вытянутая окружность"?

Comment: *"Эллипс - это окружность, вписанная в квадрат с разными сторонами" (с) Военная кафедра* Раз при x^2 и y^2 одинаковые коэффициенты - получатся нормальные окружности, не эллипсы - (x-1)^2+(y-2)^2=2*f-5 (f - значение уровня). Зачем при известной функции хранить значения в списке - не понимаю... А уж сортировать их таким образом - тем более.

Answer (score 1):

Если дан список точек, и известно, что они образуют выпуклый многоугольник, то для соединения их в правильном порядке можно сделать так:

Найти самую нижнюю точку  - с минимальным Y - если таких несколько, то взять самую левую.

Отсортировать остальные точки по полярному углу относительно данной точки.

Обойти в порядке сортировки

Comment: Берем точки (0,0), (3,0), (4,0.1), (6,0.05), (8,0.1), (10,0.05) - ну, что-то в этом духе... и получаем вместо выпуклого, но местами чуть-чуть вогнутого :) многоугольника какую-то глубокую пилу... Это я дал большие значения - а если в районе погрешности вычисления?

Comment: @Harry Часть точек приведённого набора не принадлежит выпуклой оболочке, поэтому для них и не работает. Я вообще думал, что базовой нужно взять внутреннюю точку (например, среднее трёх неколлинеарных), но для точек, заведомо лежащих на эллипсе, любая из набора может быть базовой.

Comment: На то и намекаю - что если у вас не выпуклые линии уровня (что бывает сплошь и рядом; для конкретной функции у ТС ничего сортировать вовсе не нужно) - то результат может оказаться неожиданным :)

Comment: @Harry Есть сомнения, что в вопросе первично - точки, уравнение или что-то ещё. Понятно, что моё предложение относится к идеальному случаю.

Comment: Как вариант - идти к ближайшей с тем же значением уровня? если они, конечно, расставлены равномерно, а то какой-нибудь овраг может испортить всю картину...

Comment: @Harry Для линий уровня, полученных по результатам измерений, порядок точек должен быть задан, иначе в общем случае их построить невозможно. Что есть в данном случае - нам достоверно не известно.

Comment: Это точно, достоверно известно точно одно - что достоверно ничего не известно :)